# How to iterate named groups in xpressive?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-xpressive

Say I have a `sregex` object like this one:

```
boost::xpressive::sregex::compile("(?P<firstword>\\w+) (?<secondword>\\w+)!");
```

I have not been able to find any reference in the xpressive documentation regarding this, despite xpressive supporting named groups just fine.

I know that it is possible to iterate through groups is just fine, but how would I access the groupname (if the group has a name at all)?

So, How would I iterate through the named groups?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718607/cboostregex-iterate-over-the-submatches

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The linked answer does **not** answer it, as it only quotes code directly from the header (apart from the fact that using that code would be a mere hack), it doesn't even feature an example. Why am I even trying to explain? Someone is going to tell me "that's totally a duplicate etc etc etc suck it up". SO is truly losing usefulness. And that's still put nicely, like a gentleman.

Comment: Duplicates are not about answers; they are about questions. Your little rant doesn't change that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing that we have the whole regular expression you are working on,
iIt seems to my point of view that you are trying to create a regular expression that match both of the 
the named capture, so it is useless to try to iterate over named capture.

You simply have to try something like that.

```
std::string str("foo bar");
sregex rx = sregex::compile("(?P<firstword>\\w+) (?<secondword>\\w+)!");
smatch what;
if(regex_search(str, what, rx))
{
    std::cout << "char = " << what["firstword"]  << what["secondword"] std::endl;
}
```

If the regular expression is part of a more complex pattern why not use the static named capture :
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#boost_xpressive.user_s_guide.named_captures.static_named_captures

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that using `operator[]` is currently the only way to access named groups. I wish xpressive would make the groupname accessible via member functions...